# Efficient way to get Postfix talk to SpamAssassin

Tags: email, postfix, spam, spamassassin

Traditional methods of doing this on SA wiki talk about shell scripts as content filters.

Well that's an additional `fork` syscall on every email and the volume that will flow through the machine is significant. Not to mention that shell/bash scripts themselves are hardly efficient.

Is there a more efficient way of spam filtering in Postfix?

(and no, Amavis is not an option - that's an explicit requirement handed over to me).

Comment: Make it somebody else's problem! 

There's a plethora of services and appliances that you can put in front of your SMTP server that will filter your spam for you. On a more serious note, [spamd](http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/spamd.html) is the way forward in many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forking new processes is very low cost, this is what Unix/Linux is designed to do.  Building a new spamassassin process for every email can be fairly expensive as it is a heavy weight process.  For this reason `spamd` was created.  It will fork off a few processes and keep them around to filter your email.  The pool size is dynamic and tunable.

I prefer `Exim4` which can run `spamassassin` in a couple of ways.  [These instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-setup-spamassassin-on-ubuntu-12-04) indicate that you can configure the `spassassassin` using `spamc` (the `spamd` client) as a filter.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to read about [spamd](http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.0.x/dist/doc/spamd.html). Daemonized, can talk through sockets or ports.